# CKAN Basic API jQuery Not Working

Tags: jquery, api, datastore, ckan

Playing around with the ***CKAN API***.

*Endpoints* all live e.g. http://yuj.it/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=ed654ac3-2b2b-42f2-bd39-6928cf009c0f

Using jQuery cannot get ***any*** results using jQuery AJAX...

What don't I know?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>CKAN API TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {resource_id: 'ed654ac3-2b2b-42f2-bd39-6928cf009c0f'};
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://yuj.it/api/action/datastore_search',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      alert('yay');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('boo');
    }
  });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>CKAN API TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var data = {resource_id: 'ed654ac3-2b2b-42f2-bd39-6928cf009c0f'};
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://yuj.it/api/action/datastore_search',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          alert('yay');
        },
        error: function(data) {
          alert('boo');
        }
      });
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I tried your code and it works fine "yay" and total results found "69". What have you done on your server ?

Comment: Really? Shame we missed it - because it's "boo" at the moment... In the last 48 hours we upgraded to CKAN 2.5.1 to make sure all the latest bugfixes were done and so we may have had some intermittent success at some point during the upgrade. It still doesn't work now though. Anyway, that seems to suggest the problem isn't with this code but the installation so your answer was useful. Did you run the code snippet from this page or something else because I don't see how it would give the number of results using thbis script as it is? Thanks Maxime.

Comment: Both of them, I used the snippet and my own code : alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `cache: true` to your options object will solve the problem by preventing jQuery from adding a "_" field with a timestamp value to the parameters (making each request unique prevents browser caching). If you can live with trusting CKAN to prevent caching (which is does), this will be fine.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have edited the question and also updated the snippet, since it looks as though it may help in the call but, it doesn't solve the problem. The result is still unexpected - it displays an alert, "boo".